# MailChimp Error: API Key cannot be blank

Tags: 7, emails

I'm trying to install the mailchimp addon but are stuck on getting the error message above.

So far:

- I've installed/enabled the module with version 7.x-4.0
- Loaded the PHP Library to */sites/all/libraries/mailchimp*
- Added the API Key to */admin/config/services/mailchimp*
- Enabled the *MailChimp Signup* module

The error occurs after enabling the signup module and freezes the whole website with a blank screen even though error messages are being fully displayed. When I uninstall the signup module via drush and check the admin page for the service my API key is still set.

Any pointers what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A blank white screen is indicative of some PHP error check your logs for what may caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake: I've not correctly installed the mailchimp php library. Instead of showing this in the status report page the module crashes the website.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a MailChimp account, go to your account, choose Extras / API Keys.
Copy and p[aste the API Key in the labeled field here:
/admin/config/services/mailchimp